# Programming projects for beginners?

Tags: ruby

I’m new to programming and I just read the Chris Pine “Learn to program” book. I’m wondering if anyone has any ideas for easy projects for beginners using Ruby. If anyone has any ideas, please respond!

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for StackOverflow Q&A format. SO expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, visit the help center for guidance.

Comment: You can find some useful links on the ruby-lang.org [documentation page](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/) and the ruby-community.com [links page](https://ruby-community.com/pages/links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build basic projects then here a few -
Online Examination Portal,
Web-Based Chat Server,
Attendance Management System,
Travel Agency System,
Library Management System,
Tic Tac Toe (Game),
Flappy Bird (Game).

And most basics are - Calculator(try to make it advance), todo app, alarm, a reminder, etc.